# Can I use Apple's auto-renewable Subscription Duration families, to offer add ons to the basic subscription instead of different family durations?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have not found examples of mobile apps with recurring subscription that display other than different durations of the subscription. I wonder if I could use this feature to offer different price point depending on the number of uses that can access the content. 
For example: annual subscription for 1 user, annual subscription with for 2 users ...

Answer (score 0):

Since auto-renewable subscriptions are tied to Apple ID and must be available on all devices logged into that Apple ID, this doesn't seem like an appropriate solution for you.

In fact, since you specifically mention iOS, and iOS doesn't have the concept of users, you're probably going to find yourself in a situation where you'll have to re-think your subscription model and probably roll your own external management system, complete with dealing with all the "how do I access the content via the app and still adhere to Apple's IAP rules" complications.